# Nivo Slider not working with Client Dependency Framework

Tags: umbraco, nivo-slider, client-dependency

I implemented the Client Dependency Framework for my Umbraco website:

```
<CD:ClientDependencyLoader runat="server" id="Loader" >
        <Paths>
            <CD:ClientDependencyPath Name="Styles" Path="/css" />
            <CD:ClientDependencyPath Name="Scripts" Path='/scripts' />                
        </Paths>
    </CD:ClientDependencyLoader>
```

Everything works fine on my local machine.

However, when I deployed the website on a webserver (IIS 7.5) the Nivo Slider isn't working anymore.

I compared the code on the server and on my local machine, it's exactly the same, but on the server Nivo Slider doesn't show up, and on my local machine it does.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Thanks for your help.

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

You're certain the rendered HTML is identical in both versions?

Then I would follow the javascript and css (if any) links in the rendered output, and ensure that you're getting the same js / css output.

And finally, in Chrome (preferably) hit F12 to bring up the developer tools. Check the console to see if you are throwing any javascript errors, and check network to see if any files are not being downloaded.